# circleci deploying nodejs to multiple servers (through ssh)

Tags: node.js, circleci, cicd

I have the following config.yml file for circleci to build and deploy a nodejs application on my digitalocean droplet:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:16.13.2
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          command: npm install
          name: npm install
      - run:
          command: npm run build
          name: npm build
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/
          paths:
            - .
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/base:2021.04
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "$SSH_FINGERPRINT"
      - run:
          name: ssh
          command: scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r dist/* "$SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST:/var/www"
workflows:
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
```

This works fine, but it's a small application. I'm currently building a much larger nodejs backend for a project, and I have 2 questions about using this config.yml again:

1. Is it ok to run npm install during the build job (so on the build server), en then copying it with `scp` to the server with node_modules and all the stuff already there? Or should I just ssh directly into the server, do a `git pull` command and deploy it? What we be the fastest/cheapest/safest solution?

Note: I will not need the `npm run build` command because it will not have a static website.

2. How can I deploy this to multiple servers at once?

Comment: Stackoverflow works best asking one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok to run npm install during the build job (so on the build server), and then copying it with scp to the server with node_modules and all the stuff already there? Or should I just ssh directly into the server, do a git pull command and deploy it? What we be the fastest/cheapest/safest solution?

Go with the fastest solution. That is because the fastest one is also the cheapest and the safest.

In general produce an artifact in your build. That is in short you checkout the revision on the build server and then turn it into a single package file containing the complete application. This artifact is never changed again and contains all the code to run the application.

You then can deploy the artifact for any version (release) on that many or little servers as you like, no more processing is necessary with the code. Here you can fully concentrate on speed again, as there is nothing more to build, you can choose the transport protocol and other forms of communication for your deployments perfectly fitting your needs, incl. maintaining and improving the fitness over time. The most important thing is that the deployment is automatic, fail-safe, fast, reproduce- and revert-able.